# Use value from onSensorChanged() in another method

Tags: java, android, void, android-sensors

I need to use the values from a sensor in another method. I don't know how to get values from onSensorChanged() method.

I have tried to create a global field, write in this the sensor value but outside of onSensorChanged() method the field is null.
  I have displayed the sensor value in the textView in onSensorChanged() event and it works here. The displayed valued are not null.
  When I have tried to display data from sensor outside of onSensorChanged(),  in textView in onCreate event the displayed data is null.

//global variable at class level

```
 float mean_acc;
```

//onSensorChanged() method

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    mean_acc = sensorEvent.values[1];
 }




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Initializing Sensor Services");
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);      
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:Registered");

    accelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accelDataView);
    accelView.setText(String.valueOf(mean_acc));
}
```

I don't find where is the problem. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your coding you have method `onCreate` which are called once when activity create, then after it will not call again. So, when `onSensorChanged` method call you need to set text inside that method, where you will get the `mean_acc` value, means you need to set text inside `onSensorChanged` method. So your code will be:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    mean_acc = sensorEvent.values[1];
    accelView.setText(String.valueOf(mean_acc));
}
```

This method will notify every time when this sensor changes wherever you have used it.

Comment: It works. I forgot that onCreate is called once when the activity is created.  Thanks a lot!